# ANgular js : Filter unique values and new json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, foreach

i have a list in json and ai need it with unique values

```
[
    {
        "equipmentType": "5 MEG DOCSIS",
        "status": "On Truck ",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "equipmentType": "5 MEG DOCSIS",
        "status": "Return Faulty",
        "count": 3
    } ]
```

I need like that  with unique equipmentType :

```
[
        {
            "equipmentType": "5 MEG DOCSIS",
            "On_TruckCount": 2,
            "Return_Faulty": 3

        }
]
```

Help me to find out solution of that problem 
Thanks in advance..

**EDIT**

I am trying with that but its wrong, here obj is json obj.

```
$scope.equipmentDashboard = obj;
$scope.oldEquip="";
$scope.listtest='';
$scope.test = [];
angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
    if(value.equipmentType == $scope.oldEquip.equipmentType){
        if(value.status=="On Truck ")
            $scope.listtest.onTruck = value.count;
        else
            $scope.listtest.returnFaulty = value.count;
    } else {
        $scope.test.push($scope.listtest);
        $scope.oldEquip = value;
    }           
});
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried to accomplish this mapping. So far all you have is some data and a request for someone to do your work for you. You haven't shown any attempt to solve this yourself

Comment: This tool helped me once, when I have to map something... use http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: @charlietfl i have added my code, but its wrong, dnt know right logic abot it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this I would use native javascript to create a temporary object using  `equipmentType` values as property keys since that is what is common between objects in array.

Since this is all preprocessing we don't need to worry about angular scope until the end. Ideally you would do this mapping in a service and let service return results

```
var tmp = {}
data.forEach(function (row) {
    if (!tmp[row.equipmentType]) {
        tmp[row.equipmentType] = {
            equpmentType: row.equipmentType
        };
    }
    if (!tmp[row.equipmentType][row.status] ) {
        tmp[row.equipmentType][row.status] = 0;
    }
    tmp[row.equipmentType][row.status] += row.count;

});
```

Temp object will produce:

```
{
    "5 MEG DOCSIS": {
        "equpmentType": "5 MEG DOCSIS",
        "On Truck ": 2,
        "Return Faulty": 3
    }
}
```

Then iterate over temp object to push each child object into array that will be used in $scope

```
var out = [];
for (var key in tmp) {
    if (tmp.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        out.push(tmp[key]);
    }
}
$scope.equipmentList = out;
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a0752ps7/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Wao that is awesome. thanks alot . but i am getting an error assignment to undeclared variable key on this line for (key in tmp) {

Comment: make it `for (var key in tmp)`...I was being lazy and wasn't using "use strict" in fiddle

Comment: @ charlietfl Yes thanks Its working. you save my day :)